# Python how to print an alternative 'end' statement

Tags: python

I have the following program

```
#ask user number of lines to display
user_input = input("How many lines to display? ")
line_count = int(user_input)

#ask users how many numbers on each line
user_input = input("How many numbers on each line? ")
number_count = int(user_input)

i=0

for x in range(line_count ):
  for y in range(number_count):
    print(i, end=', ')
    i+=1
  print()
```

The output, for example if the line number is 5 and the numbers on each line is 3.

```
How many lines to display? 5
How many numbers on each line? 3
0, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14,
```

My issue is the last number of each row is followed by a commma. for example

```
0, 1, 2,
```

However my desired output is a fullstop at the end of each line. for example

```
0, 1, 2.
```

How am I able to achieve my desired output?

Comment: Can you think of a rule that tells you whether the number you're about to print is the last one on the line? (Maybe something that involves the relationship between `y` and `number_count`?) Can you think of a way to use that information so that you print the comma `if` appropriate, and the period otherwise? Hint, hint.

Comment: You're printing with `end=', '` for every number - however, you don't want to print a comma after every number. After what numbers don't you want to print it? And when do you want to print a period? What should you change to make your code reflect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a condition?

```
for x in range(line_count):
    for y in range(number_count):
        if y < number_count-1:
            print(i, end=', ')
        else:
            print(i, end='. ')
     
        i+=1
    print()
```